Exponential decay of relativistic muons
I am working on an exercise that models the exponential decay of muons. The problem asks to calculate the percentage of surviving muons after $ 50 \mu s $ in two situations:

Stationary muons.
Muons that travel at $ 0.99 c $.

To get the correct result for relativist muons y calculate the relativistic mean lifetime $ \tau' = \gamma \tau $ and then calculated the number of surviving muons using a exponential decay:
$$ N(t) = N_0 e^{ - \frac{ t } { \tau' } } $$
with $ t = 50 \mu s $.
My question is, why do I have to calculate the relativistic mean half life but I don't have to do the same with the $ 50 \mu s $?. I understand that, if I did, I would get the same result than for non-relativistic muons, but I don't understand the physics behind it. If the muon is relativistic, wouldn't it perceive the $ 50 \mu s $ differently too?

That is because the question asks for the fraction of muons that remain after 50 $\mu s$ have passed in the 'lab-frame', and not in the frame of reference of the moving muons.
If you were riding along with the muons, then you would perceive the 50 $\mu s$ shrink too (when compared to the lab-frame), and in effect you would perceive nothing. But you are comparing the lifetime of muons in two cases: stationary muons and moving muons, but you, the observer, are stationary in both the cases.

Thanks, I had that intuition, but I could not phrase it appropriately to explain it to students. I still cannot wrap my head around how it would be explained for an observer traveling with the muons. Because every way I think about it, the conclusion is that an observer moving with them would perceive that more muons decay.

Yes, but an observer travelling along with muons does not have to travel for as much distance. Suppose muons are created 10 km above the surface of earth. But this is 10 km in the 'lab-frame'. In the frame of the observer coasting along with the muons, the distance to be covered is less than 10 km due to Lorentz transformations. I hope this makes it clear.
